# shorcuts in a window manager-independent way

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, xorg

I am thinking of abandoning fluxbox (or at least trying some alternatives)

My many configured keys are holding me back. I have a shortcut to open xterm, a shortcut to make a window half the screen size, to maximize, to send a window to another workspace...

I am wondering: is there a non-window manager program that just does keyboard shortcuts? Can such a program meet the use cases above? If so, I could use it to slowly transition away from fluxbox, and change WM many times until I find a better one.

Comment: those tools do some of the things I need. The most basic, though, they do not.

Comment: (maybe the problem is that the answer to this most basic question is too obvious and my google fu failed me hard). Anyway, the most basic question is "how to associate a key combination with running a program (say firefox) in a wm independent way"

Comment: fluxbox sometimes seems to lock up. It creates a borderless window for, say, my xterm, and then becomes fully unresponsive.

But mostly I want to test new things